# C++ calculating a char's order

Tags: c++

I am curious how this works to produce the provided output.  The output is 4 which is the 5th character in the alphabet (which is expected) and subsequent alphabetical characters work all the way to the z character which also returns 25.

Example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string str = "e";
  int numericalvalue = ((str[0]) - 'a');  //this line of code im trying to understand
  cout << numericalvalue;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the ASCII table?

Comment: characters are internally just numbers (see ASCII table) all you do is subtract the numbers the characters represent.

Comment: Yes but the decimal value of the character e is 101.  Is this subtracting the value of a from it and then just returning it?

Comment: There is no need to downvote a legitimate question. The user might be new to programming.

Comment: @simon: Yes. I suppose my next question is if you are familiar with integer promotion?

Comment: Yes all it does is 101(e) - 97(a) which results in 4

Comment: @AndyG no not really sorry.

Comment: @simon: That's okay. Basically what everyone has said is correct. The characters 'a' etc. are mapped from their ASCII table values. That is, there exists a direct mapping between `char` and `int`. When you subtract two characters, the result is an `int` and is formed by subtracting the corresponding entries in the ASCII table. That is we could say that `char` is 'promoted' to an `int` on subtraction.

Comment: @AndyG thank you that clarifies a lot of the mystery behind this.

In retrospect, is there a way to do this backwards? Convert int to a char output?

Comment: @simon: Indeed there is: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1647e1b7e5231342). You just need to be careful that you don't get values too large.

Comment: "4 which is the 5th character the alphabet (which is expected)": Not really unless you only care about the English alphabet. Real world text is not limited to English nor is English text limited to alphabetic characters nor are English letter characters even limited to alphabetic characters. Algorithms of this sort are rarely useful, though you can make them more appropriate to the task if you define your own alphabet (say in an array, vector, string or map) with all of the relevant characters in the problem domain. I've never had a task where the problem domain was the English alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the ASCII table.

Its character in the set is assigned a unique integer. In your case, the literal `'a'` has the value of 97 in the ASCII table and the character `e` has the value of 101. By subtracting `101 - 97 = 4` you get the final result.

More on the ASCII table can be found [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Thank you yes this is what I asked above.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`char` is an integral type, so it's implicitly convertible (specifically, it undergoes *integral promotion*) to type `int`. Each character that you can represent with a basic `char` has a numeric value from 0-255 (or -128 to 127). So saying 'a' - '0' is actually valid since it's exactly like saying `97 - 48` with `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

The character 'a' has the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) decimal value 97.

Letters after 'a' have a  decimal value greater 97.

The substraction

```
str[0] - 'a'
```

uses the ASCII decimal values which produces the letters position in the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

```
char e = 'e';
char a = 'a';
std::cout << "e = " << static_cast<int>(e) << std::endl;
std::cout << "a = " << static_cast<int>(a) << std::endl;
```

computers don't have such abstract things like "characters".
They only work with 1's and 0's.. (numbers).
The computer works with a number but knows, once it get's printed out on the screen, use the graphic that's in a .ttf file that represents that "character".